# Prevent didSelectRowAtIndexPath when a UIButton event occurs

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a `UITableViewCell` that contains a `UIButton`. The table view requires that `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` be implemented for other features of the app, but when this particular button is tapped, the button event is triggered, but `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is also triggered. I am looking for a way to prevent the table view delegate method from firing when the `UIButton` is tapped. Can anyone offer a suggestion?

Comment: What you're describing should' be happening -- touching a button should not select the cell, nor call didSelectRowAtIndexPath. What is the size of your button?

Comment: i think you can try adding `button.exclusivetouch = YES` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the original cell did not have auto-layout enabled. No sure exactly why but after enabling auto-layout and configuring the cell, the button functions properly and no longer calls didSelectRowAtIndexPath